How to predict a stack overflow? How and which memory is stored in stack?
I implemented a floodfill recursive function to check if a player will be able to reach the map exit or it'll be stacked surrounded by walls. So a simple map would look like this:
111111111
100010C01
10P000101
10C000E01
100000001
111111111

1 -> wall; 0 -> empty space; C -> collectible; P -> player;  E -> exit
And my floodfill function:
void    find_accessible_elems(t_map *map, t_elems *elems, size_t i, size_t j)
{
    elems->iterations++;
    if (map->spaces[i][j] == EXIT)
        elems->exit++;
    else if (map->spaces[i][j] == COLLECTIBLE)
        elems->collectibles++;
    map->spaces[i][j] = 'A';
    if (map->spaces[i][j + 1] != 'A' && map->spaces[i][j + 1] != WALL)
        find_accessible_elems(map, elems, i, j + 1);
    if (map->spaces[i][j - 1] != 'A' && map->spaces[i][j - 1] != WALL)
        find_accessible_elems(map, elems, i, j - 1);
    if (map->spaces[i + 1][j] != 'A' && map->spaces[i + 1][j] != WALL)
        find_accessible_elems(map, elems, i + 1, j);
    if (map->spaces[i - 1][j] != 'A' && map->spaces[i - 1][j] != WALL)
        find_accessible_elems(map, elems, i - 1, j);
}

I obviously get a stack overflow when trying to validate big maps so I did exactly the same but iterative. It's working and I could only be using the iterative one, but it is much slower than recursive, which is really sad.
void    find_accessible_elems_iter(t_map *map, t_elems *elems)
{
    t_pos_stack *stack;

    stack = new_pos(map->player.pos.x, map->player.pos.y);
    while (stack)
    {
        if (map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x] == 'A' || map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x] == WALL)
        {
            shift_pos(&stack);
            continue ;
        }
        else if (map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x] == EXIT)
            elems->exit++;
        else if (map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x] == COLLECTIBLE)
            elems->collectibles++;
        map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x] = 'A';
        if (map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x + 1] != 'A'
                && map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x + 1] != WALL)
            push_pos(stack, stack->pos.x + 1, stack->pos.y);
        if (map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x - 1] != 'A'
                && map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x - 1] != WALL)
            push_pos(stack, stack->pos.x - 1, stack->pos.y);
        if (map->spaces[stack->pos.y + 1][stack->pos.x] != 'A'
                && map->spaces[stack->pos.y + 1][stack->pos.x] != WALL)
            push_pos(stack, stack->pos.x, stack->pos.y + 1);
        if (map->spaces[stack->pos.y - 1][stack->pos.x] != 'A'
                && map->spaces[stack->pos.y - 1][stack->pos.x] != WALL)
            push_pos(stack, stack->pos.x, stack->pos.y - 1);
        shift_pos(&stack);
        elems->iterations++;
    }
}

t_pos_stack *new_pos(size_t x, size_t y)
{
    t_pos_stack *pos;

    pos = safe_malloc(sizeof(t_pos_stack), NULL);
    pos->next = NULL;
    pos->pos.x = x;
    pos->pos.y = y;
    return (pos);
}

void    shift_pos(t_pos_stack **stack)
{
    t_pos_stack *aux;

    aux = (*stack)->next;
    free(*stack);
    *stack = aux;
}

void    push_pos(t_pos_stack *stack, size_t x, size_t y)
{
    while (stack->next)
        stack = stack->next;
    stack->next = new_pos(x, y);
}

My will is to use iterative only when necessary. To do so, I tried to calculate how many stack memory the function will use and compare it to the available stack memory using ulimit -s which is saved on macro MAX_STACK_SIZE_KB on Makefile.
int has_valid_path_map(t_map *map)
{
    t_elems elems;
    t_map   accessible_map;
    size_t  stack_call_size;
    size_t  prev_stack_size;

    copy_map(&accessible_map, map);
    elems.collectibles = 0;
    elems.exit = 0;
    elems.iterations = 0;
    stack_call_size = sizeof(&accessible_map) + sizeof(&elems) + sizeof(map->player.pos.y)
        + sizeof(map->player.pos.x);
    prev_stack_size = 500; // Don't know how to calculate this
    if ((map->max_x * map->max_y - map->walls_amount) * stack_call_size + prev_stack_size > MAX_STACK_SIZE_KB * 1024)
        find_accessible_elems_iter(&accessible_map, &elems);
    else
        find_accessible_elems(&accessible_map, &elems,
            map->player.pos.y, map->player.pos.x);
    terminate_map(&accessible_map);
    return (elems.exit &&
                elems.collectibles == ft_stroccurrences(map->elems, COLLECTIBLE));
}

The iterative function results to be called much before stack overflow would occur, meaning that the future stack memory is not well calculated.
I don't even know if that's possible but my questions are:

How and which memory is stored in stack?
How can I calculate the stack memory consumption for a function?


There is no reason in the world that iterative approach would be any noticeably slower than recursive as long as both are properly implemented.

You can call getrlimit() in the program to get the stack limit, and then choose dynamically between the two methods.

All non-static local variables are stored in the stack, so you can add up their sizes. But there's also padding for alignment of variables, and bookkeeping data (saved registers, the return address). I don't think there's any easy way to find out the actual size of the stack frame.

I would go further than Eugene and say there is no way an optimal recursive solution can be faster than an optimal iterative one. Clearer/simpler expressed, maybe, but not faster. Are you sure both versions consider the same number of positions?

@EugeneSh. I just added the iterative function in case it's bad implemented but didn't find a more optimized approach.

Most C compilers implement tail-call elimination. So if you can convert your recursive algorithm to a tail-recursive algorithm, you shouldn't get a stack overflow.

@500-InternalServerError Yep. Both have the exact same iterations at the end. Should be more about handling my own stack tan other thing.

@Barmar The thing is I'm calculating more memory size than the real stack will be.

@Barmar: Re “I don't think there's any easy way to find out the actual size of the stack frame”: The question is tagged clang. Use -fstack-usage to emit a .su file with function stack use information.

The optimizer may be able to tell that the use times of two variables doesn't overlap, so it uses the same memory for both of them.

You can implement a floodfill with BFS instead of DFS, and allocate dynamic memory instead of stack recursion.

I believe the iterative version contains a major bug, so that's probably why it's running so fast. It looks like you already partially discovered this, and added the if (map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x] == 'A' || map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x] == WALL) to kinda-sorta patch over the bug, but that just hides it from yourself.

@Barmar makes so much sense but how would re-use both size_t (j&i) params if they are different cross-call?

@WeatherVane wow, reading more about it. Would wonder to see a nice solution on that but working and handling trees wouldn't make it less efficient than working with my own stack (list)?

I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking how to rewrite the function to be tail-recursive? This is non-trivial when the function contains multiple recursive calls. It will probably end up looking much like the iterative version. This is not a coincidence.

@MooingDuck Yeap, that line cheks that this stored point has not previously been checked as long as points are disordered in the stack and will always be repeated

@arzel: My point isn't the check is wrong. My point is that this check is hiding an actual bug. The iterative version has an actual bug in it, that makes it way way slower.

A circular buffer for BFS won't need more than twice the pixel elements of the image, probably less.

@Barmar I was talking about optimizer re-using memory twice used on stack

A 1000x1000 pixel image is quite small now. But a recursive DFS floodfill may well break the stack. So instead of struggling to find if the stack will cope: don't use the stack.

Then I don't understand the question. Parameters can't share memory, only variables declared locally in the function. E.g. if you have int foo = something; <code that uses foo> float bar = something_else; <code that uses bar> the compiler could use the same memory for foo and bar

@MooingDuck what kind of bug are you talking about?

I don't think he knows the bug, that's for you to debug. The fact that the iterative version is much slower indicates that there's something wrong with it. So rather than waste time here discussing recursion, go back to your debugger and figure out what's wrong with the iterative version.

@Barmar: Oh I definitely know where the bug is. He's modifying the stack while he's still using it.

@Barmar I was previously responding to "The optimizer may be able to tell that the use times of two variables doesn't overlap, so it uses the same memory for both of them." on telling you I was overcalculating stack memory I will use. I don't have any local variable on my function so I don't know what are you talking about

I see, I didn't realize that. I haven't really looked at your code in detail, my comments were just about the general problem of figuring out the stack use.

@WeatherVane definitely will give it a go soon. Thanks for that useful references!

@arzel Still haven't read this morass of code... Suggest you begin again with only the box, the player and the exit. Plot a jagged path from player to exit, then add as many obstacles as you want to cells not yet populated. Then erase the one predetermined solution path (there may be others that work, and may even be shorter.) The game board will always have at least one solution. KISS...

Despite your rudeness, I should tell you, changing requirements is not finding a solution. Hope life treats you better and waiting a helpful solution from you explaining how code could get better.

@arzel ALL code is subject to criticism. Criticising poorly written, complex code that tries to accommodate a bad design decision is not rude; it can be educational to a beginner. I've outlined what I believe to be a far simpler approach (obviating the need for "flood fill" and potential countless iterations regenerating unsolvable game boards.) Don't let your ego and attachment to "my way" get in the way of writing clean, clear, comprehensible, concise & correct code. Take a step back and look at the big picture. Others may have to work with your code in the future.

@arzel Tongue-in-cheek sardonic movie title from long ago: "Don't Raise the Bridge; Lower the River!" It pays to be weary of "bad requirements" and not give them too much oxygen.. Combine two more adages to view your problem from a better perspective: "Help! I've painted myself into a corner by putting the cart before the horse!!" Strive to not be that guy.

Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a specific question - which will come out of your best attempt to understand and locate a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the specific part of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely expect something), and don't understand why.

    if (map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x + 1] != 'A'
            && map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x + 1] != WALL)
        push_pos(stack, stack->pos.x + 1, stack->pos.y);
    if (map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x - 1] != 'A'
            && map->spaces[stack->pos.y][stack->pos.x - 1] != WALL)

In your iterative version, when it decides to queue to the square to the right, it calls push_pos(stack, stack->pos.x + 1, stack->pos.y), which presumably modifies the stack.
On the next line, when checking the square to the left, it uses the position now at the top of the stack, which is different coordinates than the prior check.  Presumably this is a bug, probably causing it to miss a bunch of squares.
Separately, The only way I can speculate that this code would work is if push_pos and shift_pos are allocating and freeing nodes on the heap.  That is the reason the iterative version is so slow.  The algorithm isn't slower, it's merely the allocations and deallocations that are slower.  Use a single large buffer and this'll be faster than the iterative version.

Just updated the question so you can see auxiliar functions. I don't think there's a bug in there but for sure it's so slow because of the allocations and frees. If you still think there's a bug, tell me. Because when I designed the code I just didn't see the first check as needed but it definetly is since the point It'll be accessing may be already filled before, points will always be repeated in the stack.

@arzel: Ah, it doesn't have the bug I suspected, because you implemented a queue, and not a stack. However, that does make it far far slower still.

Yeeep! Didn't realize it's definitely not a stack but a queue. Thanks a lot for this clarification and for your willing to help. I will try to make it buffered instead of this queue in order to save middle iterations operations. THANKS!
